# Send Base64 image from Android with JSON to php webservice, decode, save to SQL

Tags: php, android, sql, json, base64

Like the description says, I am taking a photo in Android. It is compressed and added to a `byte[]` then `base64encoded`. It sends with **JSON** to my webservice where it is "supposed" to be decoded and saved in a **SQL table row**. I can save the encoded string in a separate row so I know it's getting there.

Can anyone look at this and show me where I am doing it wrong?  *Sorry for the lengthy code. I don't want to miss something if being offered help!

**ANDROID SIDE**

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag

        int success;
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
        image = stream.toByteArray();

        String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainScreen.this);
        String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("picture", ba1));

           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(POST_COMMENT_URL,
                    "POST", params);


            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Picture Added!", json.toString());
                //finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Upload Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}

}
```

**PHP SIDE**

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $data = $_POST['picture'];
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg', true);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($im);
    $imagevariable = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

$query = "INSERT INTO pictures ( username, photo, rawdata ) VALUES ( :user, :photo, :raw ) ";

$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $user,
    ':photo' => $imagevariable,
    ':raw' => $_POST['picture']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Picture Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);

} else {
}
?>
```

Comment: What type of value is `rawdata` set as in MySQL? A Blob or something else?

Comment: I am using rawdata to confirm it is making it from the app all the way to the database. rawdata is just a text row and stored the base64 data. I don't need it after I can decode and store the image. It was just for testing.

Comment: I would also be happy using multipartentity if someone could walk me through it. I thought figuring out how to decode this base64 would be easier.

Comment: Just make sure if you are using this in a live environment its very very insecure and basically everything can be injected in the base64 version of the image string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to post my solution in case anyone else is having trouble with this. I always come to S.O. for answers so now it's my turn to help someone out. I was having problems with out of memory errors using the bitmaps. I changed it to a multipart post to upload the picture as a file and a string like their name but you could add any string to it.  The first part is the android side and below that is the php for the database.  The picture is added to a file in the directory with the move file method. The database stores the path to that picture.  I searched for two days to piece it together all from stack overflow posts.

**ANDROID**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        getLastImageId();

        new PostPicture().execute();
    }
}

private int getLastImageId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
            null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Log.d("pff", "getLastImageId: :id " + id);
        Log.d("pff", "getLastImageId: :path " + fullPath);
        return id;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

class PostPicture extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Picture");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.your-php-page.php");

        try {

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            File file = new File(fullPath);
            cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
            Log.d("sending picture", "guest name is " + guest_name);
            Log.d("Sending picture", "guest code is " + guest_code);
            entity.addPart("name",
                    new StringBody(guest_name, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            entity.addPart("code",
                    new StringBody(guest_code, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            entity.addPart("picture", cbFile);
            post.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
            String Response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.d("Response", Response);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("asdf", e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the **PHP**.  Also note that I am including my Database log in page. You can enter your d.b. password and log in here but I choose not to.

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {

if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Did not receive a name";
    die(json_encode($response));        
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}


if (empty($_FILES['picture'])) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Did not receive a picture";
    die(json_encode($response));        
} else {
    $file = $_FILES['picture'];
}


    $target_path = "uploads/whatever-you-want-it-to-be/";
            // It could be any string value above

    /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
    Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't upload file.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "You have entered an incorrect code. Please try again.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$query = "INSERT INTO name-of-table ( directory, name, photo ) VALUES ( directory, :name, :photo ) ";

$query_params = array(
    ':directory' => $directory,
    ':name' => $name,
    ':photo' => $_FILES['picture']['name']
        );

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add path to picture";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Picture Successfully Added!";
die (json_encode($response));


}

?>
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code, what is MultipartEntity and FileBody all these are erroring? thanks!

Comment: @Lion789 You might not be passing a correct file. The above code is complete except for defining the file and strings. Can you post your code in a new question and send me a link to it? I will try to help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192778/trying-to-use-async-with-image-upload-to-webserver-android There is the question I am having dilemma with trying to different ways