# Trying to use Async with image upload to webserver android?

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to use Async to be more efficient and to allow for image uploads to my webserver I have tried various methods but there is always something not working...

Here is my latest code but having problems with the return being an Int and if I change the
 AsyncTask Int then it errors because the imagePath being passed to it is a String...

This is the error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String
```

For return 0 and return serverResponseCode;

```
public class wardrobe extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // set variable for the fields
    private EditText nameField, sizeField, colorField, quantityField;
    private Spinner typeField, seasonField;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private ProgressBar progressBarField;
    private TextView imageTextSelect, resImage;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private Button uploadImageButton, postWardrobe;
    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wardrobe);

        // image upload stuff
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_photo);
        imageTextSelect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTextSelect);

        // button for upload image
        uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadImageButton);

        // button for posting details
        postWardrobe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);

        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        postWardrobe.setOnClickListener(this);


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == uploadImageButton) {
            // below allows you to open the phones gallery
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        if (v == postWardrobe) {
            // validate input and that something was entered
            if (nameField.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    || colorField.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    || sizeField.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    || quantityField.getText().toString().length() < 1) {

                // missing required info (null was this but lets see)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please complete all sections!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                JSONObject dataWardrobe = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    dataWardrobe.put("type", typeField.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("color", colorField.getText().toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("season", seasonField.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("size", sizeField.getText().toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("quantity", quantityField.getText()
                            .toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // make progress bar visible
                progressBarField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // execute the post request
                new dataSend().execute(dataWardrobe);

                // image below
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(wardrobe.this, "",
                        "Uploading file...", true);
                imageTextSelect.setText("uploading started.....");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        doFileUpload(imagepath);

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
            // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            // add to text view what was added
            imageTextSelect.setText("Uploading file path: " + imagepath);
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Here is the part I am struggling with:

```
public int doFileUpload(String sourceFileUri) {
        String upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/wardrobe";
        String fileName = imagepath;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(imagepath);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    imageTextSelect.setText("Source File not exist :"
                            + imagepath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    + " F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            imageTextSelect.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(wardrobe.this,
                                    "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        imageTextSelect
                                .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(wardrobe.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        imageTextSelect.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(wardrobe.this,
                                "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with having `doInBackground()` accept a `String`? Also, please try to minimize your code to **only** the most relevant.

Comment: but please keep the imports for reference

Comment: @SherifelKhatib really? I would say do away with them. They take up a lot of room and its usually fairly easy to see if that could be the problem.

Comment: the second code was actually placed for trying to use a different method that someone replied to me in their comments to make a new question with it, but I wanted to show both... I will remove the imports... Also, if I do change it to a string then I get an error for the 2 returns stating that they are not Strings... since they are Integers...what is with the negative?

Comment: You've got other code in there that doesn't need to be initially like other methods (`onActivityResult()` for example). You should put it the way you think it should be then tell us the errors you get so we can help with those. For example, I don't know what you are changing to a `String` and what "2 returns"... I didn't downvote but I'm guessing because all of the code and not explaining clearly

Comment: Ok I took out some of the things that can be done away with, I just know that in the past I have had people constantly say, please show all of your code... anyways the middle chunk of code is the one I am having issues with and he only returns in it are the ones being served back as int's which are giving me errors Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String - Do you have any idea what I can do to fix it : /

Comment: When you says it "errors", what do you mean? Does it give a compilation error, or a runtime error? Could you also post the text of the error?

Comment: Sorry including the error now: but it is this - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String for both return 0; and return serverResponseCode;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see many several problems here. First, you almost never (if ever) want to call `runOnUiThread()` from `AsyncTask`. Every method of `AsyncTask` runs on the `UI` except for `doInBackground()` so this usually isn't needed and often causes problems. Update the `UI` with the correct methods depending on what you are doing.

Second, I think you misunderstand what `doInBackground()` is returning. Its result is returned to `onPostExecute()` which is the 3rd `param` in your class declaration

```
private class doFileUpload extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {
```

So this means that `onPostExecute()` (which I don't see you overriding) should expect a `String` and that is what `doInBackground()` should `return`. So you should convert your `return` variables to `String` if you want to pass a `String` to `onPostExecute()`

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Typically

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

is called in `onPostExecute()` and

```
progressDialog.show();
```

would be called in `onPreExecute()` when using an `AsyncTask`. Then you don't have to create a new `Thread` in your `onClick()`.

Comment: Do you think I need AsyncTask at all, because I can take away AsyncTask and keep everything the same and it seems to work fine now except for the fact that the imagepath is showing up as null? Because is the new thread and runOnUiThread basically doing what AsyncTask does already?

Comment: Yeah as long as you run you networking code in a background `Thread`. But `AsyncTask` can be very handy. I suggest you look at my suggestions, read through the docs a couple more times (they are tricky until you get used to it), and learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: Ok I updated the code without the Async, but thanks that definitely helps in terms of clearing up Async Task... by the way do you know why when I select an image to upload why the path shows up as null? It has to do with the code in here I believe public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Comment: I do not without looking at it more. Set some breakpoints and see what would make it `null`.